# Реализация класса больших чисел с длинной арифметикой

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, biginteger, длинная-арифметика

Пишу класс для больших чисел длиной до  2^512. Использую массив `unsigned __int64`. Сложение чисел происходит неадекватно, за счёт переменной c. Алгоритм брал из книги. Можете подсказать рабочий алгоритм?

```
class BigInt {
public:
    unsigned __int64 number[8];

    BigInt() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
        {
            number[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    const BigInt operator+(const BigInt& rv) const 
    {
        BigInt res;
        unsigned __int64 c = 0, t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
        {
            t = number[i] + rv.number[i] + c;
            c = t % LLONG_MAX;
            res.number[i] = c;
        }
        res.number[7] = t;
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: Что значит «неадекватно за счёт переменной `c`»? На каких входных данных получается неправильный ответ?

Comment: Да, переменная `t` должна быть большей разрядности, чем элементы `number`. Понятно, почему?

Comment: @VladD понятно, но суть в том, что даже на малых значениях не работает.

Comment: А можно пример, на каких?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование операций `%` и `/` тут совершенно ни к чему. Это стрельба из пушки по воробьям, не говоря уже том, что такие вычисления надо производить в типе, более широком чем ваш `unsigned __int64`. А в вашем распоряжении такого типа нет.

Ни к чему тут также привязка к конкретному типу через константы вроде `LLONG_MAX` (да и почему вдруг используется *знаковый* максимум?).

Не забывайте, что величина `c` может быть только `0` или `1`.

Вот как это может выглядеть

```
BigInt operator +(const BigInt& rv) const 
{
    BigInt res;
    unsigned __int64 carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
    {
        res.number[i] = number[i] + rv.number[i] + carry;
        carry = carry ? res.number[i] <= number[i] : res.number[i] < number[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: И имеет смысл переменную `c` переименовать в `carry`, чтобы стало ясно, почему 0 или 1.

Comment: @AnT а как бы вы реализовали умножение? Алгоритм из книги опять же не работает, либо я что-то не так в нём понимаю.

Comment: @AnT кстати ваша реализация не работает  `111111111111111111111+111111111111111111111=303775478148512670606 `. Вы считаете, что такую операцию с использованием ulonglong невозможно реализовать?

Comment: @Сергей: Не совсем понимаю, каком образом вы смогли получили такой результат при помощи моей реализации. Чтобы выполнить такое сложение и посмотреть на результат необходимо еще определенное количество кода (перевод из/в десятичное представление). Почему вы решили, что "не работает" именно моя реализация, а не ваш остальной код?

Comment: @AnT, простите, не подумал об этом. Думал это конечный результат. Всё равно проблемы с пониманием. Может сможете посоветовать какие-нибудь книги, статьи, алгоритмы? Как можно число, записывающееся в массив ulonglong переводить в 10 и из10 системы?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде есть по крайней мере одна грубая ошибка: вместо

```
c = t % LLONG_MAX;
res.number[i] = c;
```

нужно

```
c = t / LLONG_MAX;
res.number[i] = t % LLONG_MAX;
```

Соответственно, финальный `res.number[7] = t;` не нужен.

Кроме того, тип `t` должен быть шире, чем тип элементов `number`.

Comment: Во-первых, почему вдруг `LLONG_MAX`, а не `ULLONG_MAX`? Во-вторых, если планируется использовать всю ширину типа, то делить надо было бы на `ULLONG_MAX + 1`. (Не забываем про `+1`). А тут уже станвится ясно, что реализация хромает вовсю.

Comment: @AnT: Тьфу ты, и правда. Там +1. Ну для реализации нужно хранить по-хорошему массив `unt32_t`, и вычислять в `uint64_t`, да.